# Can “does” be contracted?

Tags: word-usage, contractions, do

In conversation sometimes I’ll say something like this:

> What’s that do?

which uses “s” as a contraction for “does”.

**Is this a “real” contraction, or is it incorrect usage of a contraction?**

Comment: cf. "D'you" or even the colloquialism/slang "whaddya"

Comment: Did you check a dictionary?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster and Dictionary.com, "what's" is short for:

- "what is" (What's the matter?)
- "what has" (What's happened to the car?)
- "what does" (What's that mean?)

So it appears that "What's that do?" is grammatically correct.

[Merriam-Webster: **what's**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what's)

[Dictionary.com: **what's**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/what-s)

Comment: The contractions given are "What is [noun phrase]?", "What has [past tense verb phrase] (...)", "What does [noun phrase] [present tense verb phrase]?". Other syntax is possible, and each, as far as I can tell, makes the contracted verb unambiguous.

Comment: @CJDennis: Re: unambiguous - practically speaking, yes, though theoretically you could have cases like "Who's eaten?" in which the contracted verb could be either *is* or *has*.

Comment: @LarsH "Who's hungry?" = "Who is [adjective]?". "Who's eaten?" = "Who has [past participle]?". "Who's eating?" = "Who is [present participle]?". You're much more likely to say "Who's been eaten (by the mosquitoes)?" = "Who has been [past participle] (...)?". "Who is [past participle]?" doesn't work for many (most?) verbs, and when it does (weakly), it is better analysed as the verb being an adjective.

Comment: @CJDennis: We're mostly in agreement, practically speaking. Interpreting "Who's eaten?" as "Who is eaten?" is mostly for humorous purposes. However, I think you overstate the case for "Who is [past participle]?" not working, in theory. Especially since past participles do often function as adjectives, blurring the line between "Who is [adjective]?" and "Who has [past participle]?" You're right that modern colloquial speakers are more likely to use "has been" than "is" with a past participle, but that doesn't remove all ambiguity. Modern speakers understand "He's slain!" perfectly well.

Comment: *is* vs. *has* with a past participle is also distinguished, for transitive verbs, by the presence of a separate direct object: In "He's slain!" vs. "He's slain it!", the mere presence/absence of *it* makes it quite clear that the first sentence contracts *is* and the second contracts *has*.

Comment: Re: 'You're much more likely to say "Who's been eaten (by the mosquitoes)?" = "Who has been [past participle] (...)?".' And yet "He's beaten" is a normal, modern, colloquial way to speak, and is an example of "[Subj] is [past participle]"